# Getting TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property when stubbing async method

Tags: async-await, mocha.js, sinon, chai, testcafe

I am trying to write unit tests for our small but soon to grow library of testcafe business functions - i.e. thos libraries which *use* the page files, to test any of the non-simple logic.

To this end I am trying to write my first unit test for this function
entityTabs - which is an imported async module, ui is an imported non async module, accountAssignmentControls is a pagefile. Those functions mentioned by this. are defined further up in the module.
t is a testcafe import.

Initially I want to stub out all the functions and test that statAccountAssignments is called once (After that I will be testing for various combinations of the data which is passed in, but I can't get beyond the first hurdle).

I UNIT tested our non Async headless test library, but

- a) that was non-async and
- b) it was older node, so some of the structures and so on are different.

One of the developers added some units tests using chair, mocha and sinon - but these were for non async portions of the project (file handling mostly) so I can't get what he wrote to apply.

FUT

```js
     async assignAccounts(assignments) {
        await entityTabs.startAccountAssignment();
        ui.logWithTimeStamp('WAiting for Account assignment dialog to appear', 2);
            await t
              .expect(accountAssignmentControls.accountAssignmentHeader.innerText)
              .contains('Account Assignment', 'Header contains Account Assignment');
            ui.logWithTimeStamp('Header visible waiting for accounts list', 2);
            await this.checkAccountList();
        
            const assignmentsCount = assignments.length;
            ui.logWithTimeStamp('Doing ' + assignmentsCount + ' assignments: ', 1);
            for (let i=0; i<assignmentsCount; i++) {
              ui.logWithTimeStamp(i + ': ' + JSON.stringify(assignments[i]), 1);
              if (assignments[i].type === 'credit') {
                await this.assignCreditAccount(assignments[i]);
              } else if (assignments[i].type === 'debit') {
                await this.assignDebitAccount(assignments[i]);
              } else {
                await this.assignFullAccount(assignments[i]);
              }
              ui.logWithTimeStamp('Assignment done', 3);
              await t.takeScreenshot();
            };
          }
```

current failing test

```js
    import chai from 'chai';
    import sinon from 'sinon';
    import sinonChai from 'sinon-chai';
    
    import AccountAssignment from '../../business-functions/account-assignment';
    
    let accountAssignmentControls;
    // let busyLoader;
    let entityTabs;
    let ui;
    let t;
    // Register the sinon-chai extensions.
    chai.use(sinonChai);
    const expect = chai.expect;
    
    // We must turn off the no-invalid-this rule because of how mocha uses this to be the current test fixture.
    /* eslint no-invalid-this: "off" */
    
    describe('business-functions - Account assignment', function() {
      describe('AccountAssignment class', function() {
        describe('assignAccounts', function() {
          let sandbox;
    
          before(() => {
            sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
          });
    
          after(() => {
            sandbox.restore();
          });
    
          describe('when one of each assignment', function() {
            it('starts assignment', async function() {
              const fakeResponse = 'dont care';
    
              const accountAssignment = new AccountAssignment();
              t = sinon.stub();
              entityTabs = sinon.stub();
              ui = sinon.stub();
              ui.logWithTimeStamp = sinon.stub();
              accountAssignmentControls = sinon.stub();
            //  let f = sinon.fake();
              let startAccountAssignment = sandbox
                .stub(entityTabs, 'startAccountAssignment')
                .resolves(fakeResponse);
             // sandbox.stub(t, 'expect');
              sandbox
                .stub(accountAssignment, 'checkAccountList')
                .resolves(fakeResponse);
              sandbox
                .stub(accountAssignment, 'assignCreditAccount')
                .resolves(fakeResponse);
              sandbox
                .stub(accountAssignment, 'assignDebitAccount')
                .resolves(fakeResponse);
              sandbox
                .stub(accountAssignment, 'assignFullAccount')
                .resolves(fakeResponse);
              sandbox
                .stub(accountAssignmentControls, 'accountAssignmentHeader')
                .resolves(fakeResponse);
    
              sandbox
                .stub(t, 'expect')
                .resolves(fakeResponse);
              sandbox
                .stub(t, 'contains')
                  .resolves(fakeResponse);
              sandbox
                .stub(t, 'takeScreenshot')
                  .resolves(fakeResponse);
    
              await accountAssignment.assignAccounts({});
              expect(startAccountAssignment).to.be.callledOnce;
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

which when run gets

> 

TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property startAccountAssignment
at Sandbox.stub (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\sandbox.js:286:19)
at Context._callee$ (C:/Projects/Platform/PlatformTesting/UITests-NotProtractor/unit-tests/business-functions/account-assignment.tests.js:49:14)
at tryCatch (node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:65:40)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:303:22)
at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:117:21)
at step (unit-tests\business-functions\account-assignment.tests.js:21:191)
at C:\Projects\Platform\PlatformTesting\UITests-NotProtractor\unit-tests\business-functions\account-assignment.tests.js:21:437
at new Promise ()
at Context. (unit-tests\business-functions\account-assignment.tests.js:21:99)

Answer (score 12):

Not related to this but for information - use **prototype** keyword for stubbing out the instance method
i-e `sandbox.stub(deviceRegistryRepository.prototype, "getByName").resolve();`
and for static method no need to use the **prototype** keyword
i-e `sandbox.stub(myStaticClass.prototype, "getMyStaticMethod").resolve();`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was missing!

Answer (score 4):

You are not stubbing out `entityTabs` correctly, and the module you are testing is not using your stub.

To be more specific: you've declared a local var `let entityTabs;` and then later assigned that var, `entityTabs = sinon.stub();`. And finally you are attempting to stub out a method `startAccountAssignment()` on that object, but it has no such property because it's not the actual `entityTabs` module/object, and based on the code snippets you've included,  **it is not the one that the module you're testing will even use.**

Depending on how the `entityTabs` object is written (is it in it's own module? is that a singleton? is it a class?), you will need to import it, and stub out the method's you wish to mock, or you want to use something like [`proxyquire`](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to mock out `entityTabs`.

Comment: entityTabs is a class in its own module and is imported thus in the class that this function is in.        `import EntityNavigation from '../business-functions/entity-navigation';
const entityTabs = new EntityNavigation();`